# "with"文のファイルI/O以外の使い方

Tags: python

Pythonのwith文はファイルI/Oに関してよく見かけますが，それ以外に使い方があるのでしょうか？`with open('myfile') as f:`以外で，with文を使うべき，または使っているのを見かけた例は何かありますか？

Comment: withは本質的にC++の「RAII」のような使用事例です。ファイルが一番通常ですが、どの同じような場合でも使います。RAIIについてこれに読めます：http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII

Answer (score 11):

後処理しないとリソースの残る物であればなんでも良いのではないでしょうか。
python2.7 の標準添付ライブラリを軽く調べてみた感じ

- unit テストライブラリの開始と終了をハンドリングしている (unittest)
- プロセスの管理、およびプロセス間通信の同期をハンドリングしている (multiprocessing)

で使っている様です。実際には `__enter__` と `__exit__` が宣言されていればユーザ定義オブジェクトでも使用出来るので、個人的にはどんどん使っていったら良いと思います。

Answer (score 10):

既に出ているmattnさんの回答にあるように「後処理」が必要ならところには便利です。

以下のような実装がある場合:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/tmp/foo')
try:
    run()  # 何か
finally:
    os.chdir(cwd)
```

withで使えるように次のようなcdを実装して:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def cd(target_dir):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    try:
        os.chdir(target_dir)
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(cwd)
```

以下のように使えます:

```
with cd('/tmp/foo'):
    run()  # 何か
```

Fabricでwithを使う例がいくつかあります http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Answer (score 5):

`threading.Lock`を使うときはほぼ必ず`with`を使うと思います:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.lock = threading.Lock()

  def Bar(self):
    with self.lock:
      # atomic operation
```

`with`が使えて便利というのではなく、`with`を**使うべき**ケースでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

既出ではないものとしては、DB のトランザクションを扱うコンテキストでもよく見かけます。

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.execute("create table person (id integer primary key, firstname varchar unique)")

# Successful, con.commit() is called automatically afterwards
with con:
    con.execute("insert into person(firstname) values (?)", ("Joe",))

# con.rollback() is called after the with block finishes with an exception, the
# exception is still raised and must be catched
```

http://docs.python.jp/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#id11

Answer (score 2):

Python3で新たに標準パッケージに入ったmockモジュールのpatchもよく使います。

http://docs.python.jp/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

モック当てたものは必ず戻さないと他のテストに影響をあたえてしまうのでwithを使うべきものですね。

Answer (score 1):

既出以外だと pytest でも使います。

```
import pytest

def test_zero_division():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        1 / 0
```

参考: [Assertions about expected exceptions](http://pytest.org/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

trio で非同期処理のスコープを限定したい場合にも使います。